# Java parameter passing int[][]

Tags: java, parameters, parameter-passing, table-valued-parameters, dct

I am trying to write a simple DCT algorithm in java. I want my findDCT method to have as a parameter an integer array like this:

```
public class DCT {
    private Random generator = new Random();
    private static final int N = 8;
    private int[][] f = new int[N][N];
    private double[] c = new double[N];

    public DCT() {
        this.initializeCoefficients();
    }

    private void initializeCoefficients() {
        int value;

        // temporary - generation of random numbers between 0 and 255 
        for (int x=0;x<8;x++) {
            for (int y=0;y<8;y++) {
              value = generator.nextInt(255);
              f[x][y] = value;
              System.out.println("Storing: "+value+" in: f["+x+"]["+y+"]");
            }
        }

        for (int i=1;i<N;i++) {
            c[i]=1/Math.sqrt(2.0);
            System.out.println("Storing: "+c[i]+" in: c["+i+"]");
        }
        c[0]=1;
    }

    public double[][] applyDCT() {
        double[][] F = new double[N][N];
        for (int u=0;u<N;u++) {
              for (int v=0;v<N;v++) {
                double somme = 0.0;
                for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
                  for (int j=0;j<N;j++) {
                    somme+=Math.cos(((2*i+1)/(2.0*N))*u*Math.PI)*Math.cos(((2*j+1)/(2.0*N))*v*Math.PI)*f[i][j];
                  }
                }
                somme*=(c[u]*c[v])/4;
                F[u][v]=somme;
              }
            }
        return F;
    }
}
```

Now, how would I declare this method and to be able to pass 'int[][] f' as a parameter instead of using f[][] declared as a private variable and initialized in the constructor of the current class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about extracting the `initializeCoefficients` and changing the constructor from

```
public DCT() {
    this.initializeCoefficients();
}
```

to

```
public DCT(int[][] f) {
    this.f = f;
}
```

You could then use the class like

```
double[][] dctApplied = new DCT(yourTwoDimF).applyDCT();
```

---

Also, I wouldn't use `N` the way you do. I would look at the dimensions of `f` itself when applying the DCT.

That is, I would change

```
    double[][] F = new double[N][N];
    for (int u=0;u<N;u++) {
          for (int v=0;v<N;v++) {
              // ...
```

to something like

```
    double[][] F = new double[f.length][];
    for (int u = 0; u < f.length; u++) {
          F[u] = new double[f[u].length];
          for (int v=0;v<N;v++) {
              // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I agree with you that I should be more flexible with the dimensions of f. However, i do not understand why you did:

Comment: F[u] = new double[f[u].length];